# how should I optimize file rotation in golang?

Tags: go

I had designed and implemented the file rotation of file in golang.
As per design I am rotating the file based on `filesize >= FileSizeThreshold(50000bytes)` or `file duration >= FileDurationThreshold(1 minute)` (whichever is first).

Following is the implementation in golang.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "time"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "flag"
    "os/exec"
)
type FileStruct struct{
    Filename string
    CreatedAt time.Time
}
type FileRotate struct {
    Dir string
    File chan FileStruct
}

const(
    MAX_FILE_SIZE  = 50000
    MAX_FILE_DURATION = time.Minute * 1
    filename_time_format = "20060102150405000"
    MAX_TRY = 5
)
var blockingChan chan int
func main(){
    path := flag.String("dir", "", "absolute path of dir ")
    flag.Parse()
    if strings.Contains(*path, "./") {
        log.Fatalln("ERROR: please give absolute path")
    }
    if info, err := os.Stat(*path); err == nil{
        if ! info.IsDir(){
            log.Fatalln(*path," is not a directory")
        }
        log.Println("directory found..")
    } else {
        if os.IsNotExist(err){
            log.Println("directory not found..")
            log.Println("creating the directory..",*path)
            if err := exec.Command("mkdir","-p",*path).Run(); err != nil{
                log.Fatalln("failed to create the directory ERROR:",err)
            }
            log.Println("directory created successfully")
        }
    }
    filerotate := &FileRotate{*path,make(chan FileStruct,1)}
    go filerotate.FileOperationsRoutine()

    log.Println("generating file name struct..")
    filerotate.File <- GetFileStruct()
    <- blockingChan
}

func (rotate *FileRotate) FileOperationsRoutine(){
    try := 0
    var f *os.File
    for{
        if file, ok := <- rotate.File; ok{
            if f == nil {
                log.Println("WARN: file ptr is nil")
            }
            filePath := filepath.Join(rotate.Dir, file.Filename)
            fileInfo, err := os.Stat(filePath)
            if err != nil && os.IsNotExist(err) {
                log.Println("file:", filePath, " does not exist...creating file")
                _, err = os.Create(filePath)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println("failed to create the file ERROR:",err)
                    try++
                    if try == MAX_TRY {
                        log.Println("tried creating the file ",MAX_TRY," times. No luck")
                        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
                        continue
                    }
                    rotate.File <- file
                    continue
                }
                log.Println("file:", filePath, " created successfully")
                fileInfo,err = os.Stat(filePath)
            }
            sizeCheck := fileInfo.Size() >= MAX_FILE_SIZE
            durationCheck := time.Now().After(file.CreatedAt.Add(MAX_FILE_DURATION))
            if sizeCheck || durationCheck {
                log.Println("filesize of ",filePath," is ",fileInfo.Size(),"..filesizeCheck=",sizeCheck)
                log.Println("fileDurationCheck=",durationCheck)
                log.Println("rotating the file..")
                f.Close()
                f = nil
                go ZipAndSendRoutine(filePath)
                rotate.File <- GetFileStruct()
            }else{
                if f == nil {
                    f, err = os.OpenFile(filePath, os.O_RDWR | os.O_APPEND, 0644)
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Println("failed to open the file ERROR:", err)
                        try++
                        if try == MAX_TRY {
                            log.Println("tried opening the file ", MAX_TRY, " times. No luck")
                            time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
                            continue
                        }
                        rotate.File <- file
                        continue
                    }
                    log.Println("file opened in append mode")
                }
                rotate.File <- file
            }
        }
    }
}

func GetFileStruct() FileStruct{
    current_time := time.Now()
    log.Println("returning the filestruct..")
    return FileStruct{"example_" + current_time.Format(filename_time_format),current_time}
}

func ZipAndSendRoutine(file string){
    log.Println("zipping and sending the file:",file,"to remote server")
}
```

Execution log :

```
root@workstation:/media/sf_golang# ./bin/file_rotation -dir "/tmp/file_rotaion"
2017/01/16 15:05:03 directory found..
2017/01/16 15:05:03 starting file operations routine...
2017/01/16 15:05:03 generating file name struct..
2017/01/16 15:05:03 returning the filestruct..
2017/01/16 15:05:03 WARN: file ptr is nil
2017/01/16 15:05:03 file: /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150503000  does not exist...creating file
2017/01/16 15:05:03 file: /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150503000  created successfully
2017/01/16 15:05:03 file opened in append mode
2017/01/16 15:06:03 filesize of  /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150503000  is  0 ..filesizeCheck= false ...fileDurationCheck= true
2017/01/16 15:06:03 rotating the file..
2017/01/16 15:06:03 returning the filestruct..
2017/01/16 15:06:03 WARN: file ptr is nil
2017/01/16 15:06:03 file: /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150603000  does not exist...creating file
2017/01/16 15:06:03 file: /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150603000  created successfully
2017/01/16 15:06:03 file opened in append mode
2017/01/16 15:06:03 zipping and sending the file: /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150503000 to remote server
2017/01/16 15:07:03 filesize of  /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150603000  is  0 ..filesizeCheck= false ...fileDurationCheck= true
2017/01/16 15:07:03 rotating the file..
2017/01/16 15:07:03 returning the filestruct..
2017/01/16 15:07:03 WARN: file ptr is nil
2017/01/16 15:07:03 file: /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150703000  does not exist...creating file
2017/01/16 15:07:03 file: /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150703000  created successfully
2017/01/16 15:07:03 file opened in append mode
2017/01/16 15:07:03 zipping and sending the file: /tmp/file_rotaion/example_20170116150603000 to remote server
```

As seen from the logs, the utility is working as expected. 
But during the execution of this utility, CPU usage was almost 100%

[image: CPU utilization during process execution]
After stopping the utility..
[image: CPU utilization after process stopped]
I have identified the cause of this: 
`FileOperations` goroutine is running indefinitely and within this routine I am sending the file pointer on `rotate.File` channel

I am stuck at this point and not sure how to optimize this further.
Could anyone tell me how should I optimize CPU utilization for this utility?

Comment: If you're not doing this for educational purposes, I would recommend you use [logrotate](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples) instead.

Comment: Can you please explain the expected behaviour ? Is it supposed to watch a directory for files and every x duration it has to be zipped and moved to remote or it will rotate all existing log files in a directoy ?

Comment: File should be created with unique name after x duration..Each file should be monitored and rotated after filesize threshold or fileduration threshold is reached. It should not rotate all files in dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem with your code is in the for loop all the time you are passing a `FileStruct` to the channel either `old` or `new` . So there is no wait time for the channel receive for data and inside the if loop you are doing stat on the file for getting its data which mostly you must have already done

Here is strace on your program

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 93.58   11.835475        3793      3120       227 futex
  6.38    0.807279           4    192048         1 stat
  0.03    0.003284           9       366           sched_yield
  0.01    0.000759           7       114           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000271          90         3           openat
  0.00    0.000197          10        19           mmap
  0.00    0.000143          20         7           write
  0.00    0.000071          24         3           clone
  0.00    0.000064           8         8           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000034          17         2           select
  0.00    0.000021          11         2           read
  0.00    0.000016          16         1           sched_getaffinity
  0.00    0.000014          14         1           munmap
  0.00    0.000014          14         1           execve
  0.00    0.000013          13         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000011          11         1           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           sigaltstack
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           gettid
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   12.647666                195700       228 total
```

Here with in around 40 seconds there are 195k system calls

What you may do is add a wait time just after for

```
for { 
      <- time.After(time.Second)
       if file, ok := <- rotate.File; ok{
```

And you may add `fileinfo` in the `FileStruct` and on every looping you may check for that in the struct first then only do the `stat`

Here is the strace after adding `<- time.After(time.Second)`

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 65.65    0.001512          35        43         1 futex
 23.71    0.000546           5       114           rt_sigaction
  3.04    0.000070           9         8           mmap
  2.43    0.000056          19         3           clone
  2.26    0.000052           7         8           rt_sigprocmask
  0.56    0.000013           7         2           stat
  0.48    0.000011          11         1           munmap
  0.48    0.000011           6         2           sigaltstack
  0.43    0.000010          10         1           execve
  0.39    0.000009           9         1           sched_getaffinity
  0.35    0.000008           8         1           arch_prctl
  0.22    0.000005           5         1           gettid
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           write
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           openat
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.002303                   192         1 total
```

### Conclusion

For same time duration code without `time.After()` made 195K system calls where the one with `time.After(time.Second)` made only 192 system calls. You can further improve it by adding already fetched file info as a part of `FileStruct`

Comment: Thanks Sarathsp. This has really helped optimizing the CPU